# Laravel creates new CSRF token on each refresh

Tags: laravel

I'm using Laravel version 5.2.37. I have a simple HTML form in the blade view with the following line:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

When I upload the code to client's shared hosting (Cpanel, PHP 5.5.36), without submitting the form, I hit the refresh and the csrf token value keeps changing.

However, on my local machine (MacOS/Apache2/5.6.16), the csrf token persists for at least 2 minutes (per config/session.php settings). Could it be the older 5.5.36 version of PHP that's causing this?

Comment: when you submit , does it work?

Comment: if you put a value in the session then hit a route to get that value, is it there?  checking for a session regeneration issue.

Comment: When I submit (via Ajax) I get TokenMismatchException. I tried wrapping the routes into `Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () { ... }` but to no avail. Again, it should not regenerate csrf token on refresh, regardless if it's submitted or refreshed, right?

Comment: lagbox - yeah, I saw that suggestion on another thread - mine returned NULL. The issue seems to be related to _token value not being saved inside Session/Store.php attributes, while locally it does.

Comment: that would say that a new session is created on each request, as the below answer is mentioning, it could be a cookie issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I finally figured it out. Stupid me made a custom helper with a function that looked something like this:

```
<?php
function doSomething($arg)
{
    ?><p>When this function is called, 
    display <b><?php echo $arg; ?> value.</b></p>
    <?php
}
?>
```

You've probably seen a lot of functions written like this inside WordPress. Although it's not the artisan code, in most cases it will work fine, however Laravel will not tolerate this type of nonsense when dealing with helpers. So everything came back to normal after I wrote my function to return the string instead:

```
<?php    
function doSomething($arg)
{
    return '<p>When this function is invoked, 
    display <b>' . $arg . '</b> value.</p>'; 
}    
?>
```

Moral of the story - don't write ugly code. Make sure your function returns and never directly echos/prints strings, especially with helper functions.

Answer (score 1):

Try to define 'domain' in config/session.php to the right path. By default, it's set to null but on server, you should clear that.

Comment: I tried that. It didn't work. I think I'm gonna have to disable CSRF protection for the URI in VerifyCsrfToken class. If I ever find a proper solution, I'll post it here.